# How to add or increment single item of the Python Counter class

Tags: python, counter

A `set` uses `.update` to add multiple items, and `.add` to add a single one.

Why doesn't [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) work the same way?

To increment a single `Counter` item using `Counter.update`, it seems like you have to add it to a list:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for item in something:
    for property in properties_of_interest:
        if item.has_some_property: # simplified: more complex logic here
            c.update([item.property])
        elif item.has_some_other_property:
            c.update([item.other_property])
        # elif... etc
```

Can I get `Counter` to act like `set` (i.e. eliminate having to put the property in a list)?

Use case: `Counter` is very nice because of its `defaultdict`-like behavior of providing a default zero for missing keys when checking later:

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> c['i']
0
```

I find myself doing this a lot as I'm working out the logic for various `has_some_property` checks (especially in a notebook). Because of the messiness of that, a list comprehension isn't always desirable etc.

Comment: So whats wrong with your code and `Counter.update`?

Comment: I have to stick it onto a fake list. It's not a big deal; I'm just wondering if there's a thought behind no `add`.

Comment: The `update` method accept an iterable aas argument and  the iterable is expected to be a sequence of elements, not a sequence of (key, value) pairs.

Comment: Like I said in a comment - how does `add` even help you there - you're doing selections on **what** to add... I'm failing to see the point - can you give an example of how the `.add` would work?

Comment: Does `has_some_property` actually have different logic than just taking the property itself? - Also note - with the current `helper` you may get  `None` results into your `Counter` - which may be desirable or not...

Comment: It's a simple example. I have had cases with complex logic, but the thing that was really bugging me was no `add`... Re: `helper`: great point. I can imagine `Counter(helper(item) for item in something if helper(item))` but that's two calls.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Well, you don't really need to use methods of `Counter` in order to count, do you? There's a `+=` operator for that, which also works in conjunction with Counter.

```
c = Counter()
for item in something:
    if item.has_some_property:
        c[item.property] += 1
    elif item.has_some_other_property:
        c[item.other_property] += 1
    elif item.has_some.third_property:
        c[item.third_property] += 1
```

Comment: What wasn't obvious to me at first is that this works correctly even if the key you are incrementing doesn't exist in the counter yet.

Comment: @pallgeuer - Yeah, at this point we're effectively just using a `defaultdict(int)`... which is all `Counter()` is, with a few operators for combining them added in.

Answer (score 28):

```
>>> c = collections.Counter(a=23, b=-9)
```

You can add a new element and set its value like this:

```
>>> c['d'] = 8
>>> c
Counter({'a': 23, 'd': 8, 'b': -9})
```

Increment:

```
>>> c['d'] += 1
>>> c
Counter({'a': 23, 'd': 9, 'b': -9}
```

Note though that `c['b'] = 0` does not delete:

```
>>> c['b'] = 0
>>> c
Counter({'a': 23, 'd': 9, 'b': 0})
```

To delete use `del`:

```
>>> del c['b']
>>> c
Counter({'a': 23, 'd': 9})
```

Counter is a dict subclass

Answer (score 7):

There is a more Pythonic way to do what you want:

```
c = Counter(item.property for item in something if item.has_some_property)
```

It uses a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) instead of open-coding the loop.

**Edit:** Missed your no-list-comprehensions paragraph. I still think this is the way to actually use `Counter` in practice. If you have too much code to put into a generator expression or list comprehension, it is often better to factor that into a function and call that from a comprehension.

Comment: A list comprehension, a generator expression -- can do it, but with complex if/elif/elif/etc, it doesn't work.

Comment: @bahmait and how do you imagine `set.add` helps with complex `if/elif/elif` etc...?

Comment: @bahmait: Just edited. Factoring that logic into a separate function is the Pythonic way to do this, I guess. I agree that an ``add()`` method might be a nice addition, but perhaps the omission was deliberate to push people to the generator style.

Comment: @JonClements wouldn't it make things easy to read if doing a bunch of things on each pass in addition to updating the counter? I was looking for the `+= 1` for cases where slow is fine, and having all the logic in one place is nice. Does that make sense?

Comment: @bahmait yup... the answer you've accepted is definitely the most readable and scalable :)

Comment: @JonClements have edited the question in response to your comments -- appreciate your help.